# Nombrar resultado del json-objeto api con laravel-eloquent

Tags: laravel, json, api, eloquent

actualmente tengo una api con Laravel que nada mas es de consulta uso eloquent para la interacción con la base de datos, pero algunas de mis relaciones llevan de nombre tipoArea, institucionDependencia por decir algunas, el caso es que cuando mando una petición para ver el json, el objeto pasa a llamarse tipo_area, institucion_dependencia, como podría hacer que no me los renombre con el guion bajo?
Cualquier nombre que le ponga si contiene mayúscula lo convierte en un guion bajo ejemplo

**Así lo llamo**

```
public function index()
    {
        return modelo::with("ramo")
        ->with("tipoArea")
        ->with("institucionDependencia")
        ->get();
    }
```

**El modelo tipoArea**

```
public function tipoArea()
    {
        $sub = $this->hasMany('App\Areas');
        return $sub;
    }
```

**El resultado que me arroja es**

```
"tipo_area": [
            {
                "idArea": 1,
                "clave": "A",
                "valor": "Este es un valor",
            },
            {
                "idArea": 2,
                "clave": "B",
                "valor": "Este es otro valor",
            }
        ],
```

**Así lo necesito**

```
"tipoArea": [
            {
                "idArea": 1,
                "clave": "A",
                "valor": "Este es un valor",
            },
            {
                "idArea": 2,
                "clave": "B",
                "valor": "Este es otro valor",
            }
        ],
```

Comment: Creo que lo podrías castear en un [Eloquent: API Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources)

Comment: Que version de laravel estas utilizando?

Comment: 5.8 es la versión que estoy usando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad, cuando devuelves on objeto Eloquent Model o una Colección Eloquent, estos [están configurados para ser serializables JSON](https://www.php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php), y una de esas configuraciones hace lo que indicas, pasar las key que estén en *camelCase* a *snake_case*.

Cambiar eso sería complejo y no recomendable. Para estos casos (además de otras ventajas) existen las [Eloquent: API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources)

Al crear una API, es posible que necesites una capa de transformación que se encuentre entre tus modelos Eloquent y las respuestas JSON que realmente se devuelven a los usuarios de tu aplicación. Las clases Resources de Laravel te permiten transformar de manera expresiva y sencilla tus modelos y colecciones de modelos en JSON.

Entonces para tu caso podrías crearte una API Resource:

```
php artisan make:resource Modelo
```

Que se vería similar a esto:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Modelo extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            // otras propiedades...,
            'tipoArea' => $this->tipoArea,
        ];
    }
}
```

Finalmente en el controlador retornas la API Resource en vez de la colección eloquent:

```
use App\Modelo;
use App\Http\Resources\Modelo as ModeloResource;

/...

public function index()
{
    $collection = modelo::with("ramo")
        ->with("tipoArea")
        ->with("institucionDependencia")
        ->get();
    return ModeloResource::collection($collection);
}
```

Comment: Pero en el recurso añades al arreglo atributos (o campos), no son relaciones, las relaciones son las que me convierte en camelCase, si traigo un campo normal, si me lo deja correctamente

Comment: Excelente Master, ya quedó, muchas gracias, ahora a seguir trabajando, tenía 2 semanas trabado en eso.
Tal vez no sea lo mejor, pero necesito mandar información con ese formato especifico a sistemas ya elaborados, por eso mi insistencia en la forma.
Muchisimas gracias bro